# How to fill up each element in a list to given columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe as shown.

[image]

I have a list now like [6,7,6]. How do I fill these to the my 3 desired columns i.e,[one,Two,Four] of dataframe? Notice that I have not given column 'three'. Final Dataframe should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 4, 8]],
                  columns=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])

values = [6, 3, 6]
lst = ['One', 'Two', 'Four']

df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=lst), ignore_index=True)
```

or a dict:

```
df = df.append(dict(zip(lst, values)), ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
   One  Two  Three  Four
0  2.0  4.0    4.0   8.0
1  6.0  3.0    NaN   6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
columnstobefilled = ["One","Two","Four"]
elementsfill = [6,3,6]
for column,element in zip(columnstobefilled,elementsfill):
    df[column] = element
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the list values to be in specific places you have to specify where each value should go. One way to include this is to use a key value pair object, a dictionary. Once you create that you can use [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to include it as a row in your dataframe:

```
d = {'one':6,'Two':7,'Four':6}
df.append(d,ignore_index=True)

   one  Two  Three  Four
0  2.0  4.0    4.0   8.0
1  6.0  7.0    NaN   6.0
```

Dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':2,'Two':4,'Three':4,'Four':8},
                  index=[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'One':2, 'Two':4, 'Three':4, 'Four':8}, index=[0])
new_row = {'One':6, 'Two':7, 'Three':None, 'Four':6}
df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   One  Two  Three  Four
0  2.0  4.0    4.0   8.0
1  6.0  7.0    NaN   6.0
```